# Azure ARM: Create Linux VM from storage account using access keys

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to create a Virtual Machine (Ubuntu Linux) in Azure using ARM template, where I will store the .vhd file in a storage account and while deploying in a separate Azure resource group (Client) the storage account will be accessed using access keys to deploy the VM.

I used the below command to copy the VHD to a storage account in my RG.

```
az storage blob copy ​ start ​ --destination-blob​ $destinationVHDFileName
--destination-container​ $storageContainerName ​ --account-name​ $storageAccountName
--account-key​ $storageAccountKey ​ --source-uri​ $sas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Vm with your own vhd file, you can create an Azure managed image with the VHD file then create VM with the image. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/imaging) and here

For example

1. Create Azure managed image

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "images_testimage_name": {
            "defaultValue": "testimage1",
            "type": "String"
        },
       "blobUri": {
            "defaultValue": "<your vhd file url>",
            "type": "String"
        },
       "location": {
            "defaultValue": "",
            "type": "String"
        }

    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/images",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('images_testimage_name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "osType": "Linux",
                        "osState": "Generalized",
                        "diskSizeGB": 30,
                        "blobUri": "[parameters('blobUri')]",
                        "caching": "ReadWrite",
                        "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": [],
                    "zoneResilient": true
                },
                "hyperVGeneration": "V1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create VM

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
     ... other resource
        {
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
                        }
                    },
                    "imageReference": {
                        "id": "<the resource id of the image you create in step1>"
                    }
                },
                ... other configurations
            }
        }
    ]
}
```